# Can you use Variable and Optional arguments in the same sass mixin?

Tags: css, sass

I'm looking to create a global gradient mixin. My question is pretty much in the title, or example below. I couldn't find anything on it in the docs or through google.

```
@mixin gradient($fallback, $color-stops..., $dir: "") {
   @if $dir != "" {
  background-color: $fallback; //fallback for older browsers
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient($dir, $color-stops);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient($dir, $color-stops);
  background: -o-linear-gradient($dir, $color-stops);
  background: linear-gradient($dir, $color-stops);
}//end if
@else {
  background-color: $fallback; //fallback for older browsers
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient($color-stops);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient($color-stops);
  background: -o-linear-gradient($color-stops);
  background: linear-gradient($color-stops);
} //end else
}
```

thank you

Comment: Did you try compiling it and see what happens?

Comment: Yes, just compile and see if sass complains :)

Comment: I had before I submitted the questions and got Syntax error: Required argument $color-stops must come before any optional arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both, but the variable argument has to come last:

```
@mixin gradient($fallback, $dir: "", $color-stops...) { ... }
```

In your case that's probably not ideal. I recommend passing color-stops as a list to one single argument instead. All you need to do is add parenthesis around them:

```
@mixin gradient($fallback, $color-stops, $dir: "") { ... }
@include gradient(red, (to left, red 50%, blue));
```

Though I'm not sure what the `$dir` argument actually does...

Comment: I had thought this would work as well but it came out to the comment above; sass complaining that $color-stops come before the optional argument